Issues with dynamically importing variables into namespace
I have an array of hashes in Perl. I would like to loop through the array and execute some code specified in a string on each of the hashes (remark: I would not like to discuss this approach or its security considerations; let's focus on how it can be done). An example implementation could look like this:
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = [
  {foo => "foo1"},
  {foo => "foo2"},
  {foo => "foo3"},
  {foo => "foo4"},
];

my $code = q{say $item->{foo}};

foreach my $item (@$list) {
  eval qq{$code};
}

As expected, this prints:
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4

So far, so good. However, I would like the array and hash data structure to be transparent to the code snippet, i.e. the code snippet should be able to use $foo instead of $item->{foo} etc. Therefore, I am trying to import the hash entries into the main namespace. (Again, I would like to discuss how to do this, not whether I should do it.)
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = [
  {foo => "foo1"},
  {foo => "foo2"},
  {foo => "foo3"},
  {foo => "foo4"},
];

my $code = q{say $foo};

foreach my $item (@$list) {
  foreach my $key (keys %$item) {
    $main::{$key} = \$item->{$key};
  }

  {
    no strict "vars";
    eval qq{$code};
  }
}

I would expect this to work, but it does not (fully). This code prints:
Use of uninitialized value $foo in say at (eval 1) line 1.

foo2
foo3
foo4

For some reason, the first item is not processed correctly.
I have tried several ways to circumvent this or find out more about what is wrong. The following changes all work (potentially with a warning about $foo only being used once):

replace eval qq{$code} with a literal say $foo
replace my $code = q{say $foo} with my $code = q{say ${$main::{foo}}} (however, $main::foo does not suffice)
use the variable $foo somewhere before, e.g. put a { no strict "vars"; my $bar = $foo; } before the outer foreach loop
explicitly create the package variable by inserting eval sprintf('our $%s;', $key); before $main::{$key} = \$item->{$key};

Option 4 is what I would do now. It feels a bit hacky, but does the job. However, I would still like to understand why this is necessary and whether there is a better way to fix it.
UPDATE: As pointed out by TLP, a simpler way to achieve this is to use a symbolic reference instead of symbol table manipulation. See my own answer to the question. However, I would still like to understand why the symbol table approach does not work out of the box.

Oh, I see. You think $main::{$key} should be the same as $foo?

Try ${$key} instead. With the no strict vars enabled.

Regarding $main::{$key}: Yes, $key contains the string foo and $main::{$key} therefore refers to entry foo in the symbol table.
Regarding ${$key}: Good point! I was clearly thinking too complicated. (It is no strict 'refs' in this case, though.)

I still can't get it to work. I have to say, while interesting from an academic point of view, this is a hack, and a very poor design choice. It does feel very much like an XY problem. I.e. this is the wrong solution to your problem.

@TLP For a solution using your suggestion see my own answer to the question. Regarding the XY problem, I deliberately did not add my reasoning for choosing this approach to the question because I considered it too much of a digression. In short, the reason is that both the code snippet and the data are only known at runtime and the data structure should be transparent to the person writing the code snippet.

A symbolic reference is a simpler way than manipulation of the symbol table. Here is an adaptation of the code in the question that solves the problem:
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = [
  {foo => "foo1"},
  {foo => "foo2"},
  {foo => "foo3"},
  {foo => "foo4"},
];

my $code = q{say $foo};

foreach my $item (@$list) {
  foreach my $key (keys %$item) {
    no strict 'refs';
    ${$key} = $item->{$key};
  }

  {
    no strict 'vars';
    eval qq{$code};
  }
}

Importantly, the solution above makes a copy of the values in the data structure instead of creating an alias. This matters if the code in $code modifies the values. The modified code example below showcases this. It also contains (commented out) the fixed symbol table manipulation, which creates an alias instead, thereby allowing the original data structure to be modified by $code. See also the answer by clamp.
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = [
  {foo => "foo1"},
  {foo => "foo2"},
  {foo => "foo3"},
  {foo => "foo4"},
];

my $code = q{$foo .= '_bar'; say $foo};

foreach my $item (@$list) {
  foreach my $key (keys %$item) {
    no strict 'refs';
    ${$key} = $item->{$key};  # copy
    # *{$key} = \$item->{$key};  # alias
  }

  {
    no strict 'vars';
    eval qq{$code};
  }

  say $item->{foo};
}


It's not exactly clear whether you want to have an alias or a value copy in $main::foo.  The syntax for an alias would be *foo = \$bar (assign a scalar ref to a typeglob) see perlmod:
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = [
  {foo => "foo1"},
  {foo => "foo2"},
  {foo => "foo3"},
  {foo => "foo4"},
];
my $code = q{say $foo};
foreach  my $item (@$list) {
  foreach my $key (keys %$item) {
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"main::$key"} = \$item->{$key}; # alias
    # *{$key} = \$item->{$key};       # alias
    # ${$key} = $item->{$key};        # value
  }

  {
    no strict 'vars';
    eval qq{$code};
  }
}


You are right, I did not make it clear in the question whether I am looking for alias or copy because it does not matter much in my particular use case. However, it obviously can be very important, so thanks for pointing that out. Thank you also for fixing the typeglob assignment, this is what I was looking for originally. I have also modified my own answer to include your points.

I would put the entire loop structure inside its own global-scope block, with no strict 'refs'; as its first line, just to make it much more clear to those who need to read the code in the future. I'd also replace foreach() with for(), which is much more idiomatic nowadays. Although the no strict 'refs' line is only executed once at compile time, the way you've written it has it two layers deep. Also, you have an indenting issue which hides things even further. One last thing, the no strict; is an extremely dangerous proposition

@stevieb : Fixed indentation and added back strict 'vars'. Your other remarks seem like a matter of taste to me. If in the OPs codebase foreach is preferred over for I see no reason to change that. Also having nostrict 'refs' in a scope close as possible to where its effect is needed  makes sense to me.

Declare $foo before assigning to it:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $list = [ map { +{foo => "foo$_"} } 1 .. 4 ];

our $foo;
my $code = q{say $foo};

for my $item (@$list) {
    for my $key (keys %$item) {
        $main::{$key} = \$item->{$key};
    }
    eval $code;
}

You can then throw away eval and use code references instead to increase security:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $list = [ map { +{foo => "foo$_"} } 1 .. 4 ];

our $foo;
my $code = sub { say $foo };

for my $item (@$list) {
    for my $key (keys %$item) {
        $main::{$key} = \$item->{$key};
    }
    $code->();
}


Thank you for your answer. Regarding declaring $foo: Yes, that works, but foo is hard-coded now. I only know at runtime which variables are needed. Hence, the eval approach (also using our in my option 4 in the question. Regarding the code reference: Again, this only works if the code to be executed is known at compile time.
